# What is the pattern called when getters take responsibility for the setting?

Tags: design-patterns, patterns-and-practices

I've been heavily using a pattern for years now, but I don't know what it's called.

It looks like this....

```
class xzy
{

  public function getFoo()
  {
    if ( undefined(this.foo) )
    {
       this.foo = new Foo;
    }
    return this.foo
  }

  public function setFoo(foo)
  {
    this.foo = foo;
    return this;
  }

  public function getResult()
  {
    if ( undefined(this.result) )
    {
       this.result = this.getFoo().action();
    }
    return this.result;
  }

}
```

It find it great for testing yet still allows for a high level of encapsulation.  It's also great for drying up code. I also very rarely use a constructor. I'm now in a position where I could really do with specifying the pattern in some documentation but I don't know what it's called and it's a hard thing to try and Google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)

I like to use it to cache a calculation result that is expensive and it allows me to clear the cache easily when one of the variables change (and when there are likely more changes waiting to happen):

```
public Rectangle getBoundingRect(){
    if(bbox==null){
    bbox=calculateBBox();
    }
    return bbox;
}

private Rectangle calculateBBox(){
    //expensive operation
    return //...
}

public void updateGeom(){
    bbox=null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking it was lazy loading, so I wasn't a million miles off. I also use it to DRY up code. I'm in love with it but it's causing me problems when I have to collaborate with other people. I get some weird looks.

Comment: +1 Also known as `lazy instantiation`

Comment: @tomwrong If there's data access, you can call it lazy loading. I'd call it lazy loading in conversation anyway ... fewer syllables :)